# N2 Installation from NuGet Packages - What's Next?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, n2

I'm trying to install N2 CMS using the NuGet packages for version 2.2.2.2.  I want to also install the Dinamic Razor templates as well.  Thus far, I've created a new MVC solution in Visual Studio 2012, installed Lucene.net RC, installed N2 CMS 2.2.2.2 and the Dinamico template package.

My solution now contains a N2 folder with a zip file therein.  Do I need to unzip the file to extract the bits for use in the solution?  What must be done to enable use of SQL Server?  Finally, how does the N2 installation process work?  Do I deploy my solution to IIS and then browse my site from there?  I've seen step by step installations for Web PI and WebMatrix.  However, I'm interested in locating a one stop source for successfully building and installing the N2 bits.  Does anyone know if this exists?

Answer (score 0):

Although the documentation is not fully complete. It does appear to provide enough information to integrate N2 into an MVC solution.

The documentation can be downloaded as a word document from the link below:

http://n2cms.codeplex.com/releases/view/70951